# Override console.log in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Sometimes we leave `console.log` debug statements in our javascript.  Just so they don't accidentally make it into production (where some old browsers will die on these), we tried doing this in our first coffeescript file:

```
if !console?
  console = {log: ->}
```

But this seems to kill all ability to use console.log in development, even in browsers that support it (webkit).

`console?` returns false, so the if block doesn't run, but it still seems to overwrite the functionality of `console.log`.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```
if !console?
  console = {log: ->}
```

becomes this JavaScript:

```
var console;

if (typeof console === "undefined" || console === null) {
  console = {
    log: function() {}
  };
}
```

The result is that you have a local `console` variable that shadows the `window.console` that you're looking for.

The solution is to say exactly what you mean:

```
if 'console' !of window
  window.console = { log: -> }
```

Note that `console` is always localized to `window` here so you don't accidentally create any shadows.

There are various ways to say `if 'console' !of window` that will have the same effect, use whichever one is clearest for you.

Comment: I'd just use `if window.console?`, personally.

Comment: @ChrisHeald: Or even `window.console ||= log: ->`

Answer (score 0):

My approach has been to define a `DEBUG` (or `print`) function to use instead of `console.log`.  The default, production definition is

```
DEBUG = () ->
```

and prior to any test code (e.g. at the end like Python `if __name__...` block):

```
if not module.parent? and (!process.argv[2]? or process.argv[2]!='nodebug')
    DEBUG = (arg...) ->
      arg.unshift('==> ')
      console.log arg...
```

or simply

```
DEBUG = console.log
```